# Winning strategy in a number theory game

Tags: number-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Two people play a game, lets call them A and B. There are $n$ stones on a table and players start to remove them. They can remove $p-1$ stones at once where $p$ is a prime number. Whoever takes the last stone, wins. Show that if player A starts then player B has a winning strategy for infinite number of $n$.

My thoughts so far:

It seems that whoever can take stones such that 3 stones remain will win. I haven't figured out when it is impossible for player A to do so.
Player B needs to avoid a position where there are $p+2$ stones remaining. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $B$ can only win finitely many starting positions.  We know there is at least one, which is $3$.  There is a largest one, call it $N$.  Now consider the starting position $(N+1)!+N$.  There are no primes in the range $[(N+1)!+2,(N+1)!+N+1]$, so $A$ must leave a position larger than $N$.  We assumed all numbers larger than $N$ were wins for the first player, so $B$ can use the first player strategy and win.  This violates our assumption that $N$ was the largest second player win.

Comment: I would suggest adding that $3$ is an obvious starting postiton where $B$ wins (as OP implied). Because if there was *no* starting position where $B$ wins, your argument breaks down.

Comment: Wouldn't we have to prove that for arbitrary n there exists a winning strategy for either player or it is safe to assume there is?

Comment: @MarkusPunnar:  We have to show the game terminates and does not draw, but the fact that one can take $1$ is enough for that.  Then the usual Sprague-Grundy theory applies.  Every position is either $P$, a win for the previous player or $N$, a win for the next player.  An $N$ position is one that can reach a $P$ position, a $P$ position is one that can only reach $N$ positions.  We are asked to prove there are infinitely many $P$ positions

Comment: @MarkusPunnar:  this kind of strategy stealing argument is fairly common.  Note I have given $B$ no indication how to find a winning strategy, I have just shown that one exists.

Comment: As an aside, I imagine the $P$ and $N$ stuff (though probably not the notation) predates "the usual Sprague-Grundy theory". The idea is basically a proof of [Zermelo's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%27s_theorem_%28game_theory%29).